# Can I take CUC/CUP notes out of Cuba?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, money, cuba

I'm visiting Cuba soon and have just read an [excellent answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58511/can-someone-explain-cubas-two-currency-system-and-the-consequences-for-foreigne) about the Cuban CUC and CUP bank notes.

I have a retired friend who collects bank notes and I usually bring him back some low-value bills from interesting places - but I see it's forbidden to "export" CUCs.

My question is, if I wanted to bring 1 or 2 of low-denomination CUC and/or CUP notes out with me, am I going to be searched & in big trouble if discovered or are they only worried about taking big bundles of cash out?

Comment: Forbidden by whom? I successfully took both CUCs and CUPs out of Cuba without any glitch :)

Comment: Forbidden by the authorities apparently - if you read the linked post about currency and/or Rough Guide etc. they have tourist / exchangeable currency and local / non-exchangeable currency.

Comment: Life is short, break the rules :) I don't think is it observed strictly.

Comment: Life is also too short to be detained by the authorities 1000 miles from home in a communist country whose language you don't speak... hence my question! If they don't take it too seriously I'm happy to accidentally leave a couple of bills in my backpack, but I don't really want to miss my flight home over it!

Comment: I do not think they are strict about this, it's probably intended to prevent extracting somehow large amounts, but stil...

Comment: The law that imposed these restrictions was passed in 2012, as far as I know it is still in place. Take a look at this blog post for a related incident: http://www.bravotv.com/blogs/im-an-expert-traveler-but-i-accidentally-broke-this-one-rule-and-almost-went-to-jail-dont-let

Comment: By the way the blog post mentions that a bank rep told the author that she could change her CUC to USD at her home country, [this is either a mistake from the bank, or a lie](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Travel-g147270-c150737/Cuba:Caribbean:Money.Misconceptions.html)

Comment: Could you not just mail some banknotes home?  That might be simpler than risking getting caught by the Cuban authorities.  Include a postcard in the envelope, so that you that the envelope seems reasonable.

Comment: @Jim MacKenzie that won't work in Cuba. All outgoing mail in Cuba is inspected by customs, x-rayed, and if anything suspicious is found they will open the package or envelop with no mercy.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well I made it home safe despite accidentally leaving a couple of un-spent CUC notes in my wallet so I guess that's a sort-of answer.

Comment: Just about as much as an answer as if you believe that shop-lifting is legal because you tried it once and didn't get caught.

Comment: Not really - despite the warnings no-one was searched, no-one was asked about notes, etc. so I'm reporting that it wasn't enforced and therefore is (or was) low-risk.

Comment: You are right. I also know a lot of people, who have been driving cars their entire life without ever having their driver's licence checked by the police. If the risk is so low being caught, why not just fuck any laws or regulations and do whatever we want?

Comment: I think you're taking this a tad too seriously - the original question makes it obvious that it is _not allowed_ to take notes out, the whole question is about being a _little bit naughty_ to please a friend. It's not like I was asking about the best way to dispose of a body or smuggle a few kilos of heroin.

Comment: Currency smuggling can be serious enough. The question is not about being *a little bit naughty*, but about visiting a country as a tourist and blatantly ignoring the local laws.